# How to select one result from one unknown column in each row where the sum = @Number

Tags: sql

I have a known number, x and several named columns (ix, col1, col2, col3) and need to select a single value from either col1, col2, or col3 from each row (not necessarily the same column) where the total adds up to the known number x. I am having a difficult time trying to figure out the logic for this.

There is no chance of multiple result sets using the numbers in the columns, but one column from each row MUST be returned, with all columns returned adding up to the number X.

Ideally it would be something like this:

SELECT * as results
FROM table
WHERE sum(results) = number

however I can't use * in the sum statement, and it is possible that more than one result from each column (although being in separate rows) could be returned. SO I can't do  Select col1, col2 col3 etc

Comment: Sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: Answer: 3.4642857143, 0.9285714286, 5.5357142857

Comment: First Row: VALUES('1', '0.75', '0.8214285714', '0.8928571429', '1.0357142857', '1.0357142857', '1.1071428571', '1.1785714286', '1.25', '1.3214285714', '1.3928571429', '1.4642857143', '1.5357142857', '1.6071428571',

Comment: '1.6785714286', '1.75', '1.8928571429', '2.0357142857', '2.1785714286', '2.3214285714', '2.4642857143', '2.6071428571', '2.75', '2.8928571429', '3.0357142857', '3.1785714286', '3.3214285714', '3.4642857143',

Comment: '3.6071428571', '3.75', '4.0357142857', '4.3214285714', '4.6071428571', '4.8928571429', '5.1785714286', '5.4642857143', '5.75', '6.0357142857', '6.3214285714', '6.6071428571', '6.8928571429', '7.1785714286', '7.4642857143', '7.75', '8.3214285714', '8.8928571429', '9.4642857143', '10.0357142857', '10.6071428571', '11.1785714286', '11.75', '12.3214285714', '12.8928571429', '13.4642857143', '14.0357142857', '14.6071428571', '15.1785714286', '15.75', '16.8928571429', '18.0357142857', '19.1785714286', '20.3214285714', '21.4642857143', '22.6071428571', '23.75');

Comment: Second Row: VALUES('2', '0.5', '0.5714285714', '0.6428571429', '0.7857142857', '0.7857142857', '0.8571428571', '0.9285714286', '1', '1.0714285714', '1.1428571429', '1.2142857143', '1.2857142857', '1.3571428571', '1.4285714286', '1.5', '1.6428571429', '1.7857142857', '1.9285714286', '2.0714285714', '2.2142857143', '2.3571428571', '2.5', '2.6428571429', '2.7857142857', '2.9285714286', '3.0714285714', '3.2142857143', '3.3571428571', '3.5', '3.7857142857', '4.0714285714', '4.3571428571', '4.6428571429', '4.9285714286', '5.2142857143', '5.5', '5.7857142857',

Comment: '6.0714285714', '6.3571428571', '6.6428571429', '6.9285714286', '7.2142857143', '7.5', '8.0714285714', '8.6428571429', '9.2142857143', '9.7857142857', '10.3571428571', '10.9285714286', '11.5', '12.0714285714', '12.6428571429', '13.2142857143', '13.7857142857', '14.3571428571', '14.9285714286', '15.5', '16.6428571429', '17.7857142857', '18.9285714286', '20.0714285714', '21.2142857143', '22.3571428571', '23.5');

Comment: Third Row: VALUES('3', '0.25', '0.3214285714', '0.3928571429', '0.5357142857', '0.5357142857', '0.6071428571', '0.6785714286', '0.75', '0.8214285714', '0.8928571429', '0.9642857143', '1.0357142857', '1.1071428571', '1.1785714286', '1.25', '1.3928571429', '1.5357142857', '1.6785714286', '1.8214285714', '1.9642857143', '2.1071428571', '2.25', '2.3928571429', '2.5357142857', '2.6785714286', '2.8214285714', '2.9642857143', '3.1071428571', '3.25', '3.5357142857', '3.8214285714', '4.1071428571',

Comment: '4.3928571429', '4.6785714286', '4.9642857143', '5.25', '5.5357142857', '5.8214285714', '6.1071428571', '6.3928571429', '6.6785714286', '6.9642857143', '7.25', '7.8214285714', '8.3928571429', '8.9642857143', '9.5357142857', '10.1071428571', '10.6785714286', '11.25', '11.8214285714', '12.3928571429', '12.9642857143', '13.5357142857', '14.1071428571', '14.6785714286', '15.25', '16.3928571429', '17.5357142857', '18.6785714286', '19.8214285714', '20.9642857143', '22.1071428571', '23.25');

Comment: The actual table has a primary key IX, and 64 columns of data per row.

Comment: The number X is 9.9285714286 where one column is returned from each row, totaling the number x

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple select statements and specify a different condition each time.

```sql
SELECT FirstColumn,
       SecondColumn
FROM [Table]
WHERE FirstColumn + SecondColumn = x
UNION
SELECT SecondColumn,
       ThirdColumn
FROM [Table]
WHERE SecondColumn + ThirdColumn = x
UNION
SELECT FirstColumn,
       ThirdColumn
FROM [Table]
WHERE FirstColumn + ThirdColumn = x
```

Or use `CASE...WHEN`, and filter by the conditions to ignore null results. `Case` returns a single result, so you need to repeat the case condition to return different columns:

```sql
SELECT CASE
           WHEN FirstColumn + SecondColumn = x THEN FirstColumn
           WHEN SecondColumn + ThirdColumn = x THEN SecondColumn
           WHEN FirstColumn + ThirdColumn = x THEN FirstColumn
       END AS FirstMatch,
       CASE
           WHEN FirstColumn + SecondColumn = x THEN SecondColumn
           WHEN SecondColumn + ThirdColumn = x THEN ThirdColumn
           WHEN FirstColumn + ThirdColumn = x THEN ThirdColumn
       END AS SecondMatch
FROM [Table]
WHERE FirstColumn + SecondColumn = x
  OR SecondColumn + ThirdColumn = x
  OR FirstColumn + ThirdColumn = x
```

Comment: thank you however I added some more to the question which should clarify the end result. also, there is sample data in a previous comment. thank you

Comment: @Sunsing Checked the data and result. This is the "subset sum" problem -look it up-. I'm not sure this can be solved in any efficient or elegant manner in SQL. You can look into using CTE or find existing solutions and tweak them to your needs.